# Show that the following classes are not closed under ultraproducts: the class of torsion groups; the class of simple groups;

Tags: logic, model-theory

Hi been trying to solve this question :

Show that the following classes are not closed under ultraproducts:
(a) the class of torsion groups;
(b) the class of simple groups;

Thought about showing that they are closed under isomorphism and to show that they are not axiomatizable hence they are not closed under ultraproducts, couldn't really proof that tho, so I would like some help!
Thanks!

Comment: For torsion groups, isn't it enough to note (or demonstrate) that an ultraproduct of $C_n, n \in \Bbb N$, is not torsion?  Here, $C_n$ denotes the cyclic group (unique up to isomorphism) of order $n$.  For simple groups, use an ultraproduct of $C_p$ for $p$ prime.

Comment: @Robert Shore that seems correct wow thank you! Mind giving a rough sketch of how it looks? my group theory knowledge is kinda off right now!

Comment: For torsion groups, note that for any $n \in \Bbb N, x^m \neq 1 \forall m \leq n$ for all but finitely many components of the ultraproduct.  For simple groups, you just need to show that one torsion element exists -- then the set of all torsion elements is a proper subgroup of an abelian group, and therefore is normal.

Comment: Thanks! thats really helpful! @Robert Shore